# selecting objects in a vector based on a vector of booleans in c++

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector

I have a vector of booleans (*e.g.* true, true, false, false) and another vector of the same size, but of a different type. 
I want an output vector with the elements of the second vector in correspondence of a true in the first vector.

Basically, I'm trying to reproduce what in Julia or R is done by:

```
vec = vec[to_select]
```

I have tried to write a copy_if, but well, let's say that the compiler didn't quite like it. This is what I have

```
  auto it = copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), to_select.begin(), vec.begin(), [](auto& val, auto& cond){return cond;});
```

And then to resize it:

```
vec.resize(std::distance(vec.begin(), it));
```

Any suggestion to do that in a clean and fast way, possibly without creating a new vector?

Comment: "The compiler didn't quite like it", what didn't it like?

Comment: If you dont want to make a new vector you can use `std::remove_if`. However since you are using a different list as your predicate I don't think you can avoid using a for loop

Comment: Well, long story short, there wasn't a matching call for 3 iterators, from what I got. I can't copy the error since a maximum limit of character is reached.

Comment: *without creating a new vector* Does that mean you no longer need the old vector, so it can be reused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectors have guaranteed contiguous elements. As such, a remove/erase idiom is employable here by using pointer arithmetic on the elements when calculating the offset into the retention flags sequence:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    std::vector<bool> flags = { true, true, true, false, true, false, false, true };

    vec.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
        [&](int& arg) { return !flags[&arg - vec.data()]; }), vec.end());

    for (auto x : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 5 8
```

Obviously it is critical that the size of `vec` and `flags` is the same (more precisely, that `flags` is at least as large as `vec`).